# Geometry Nodes: Delete specific points from a curve by index

Tags: bezier-curves, geometry-nodes

I have a Bezier Curve with 7 points, and a Geometry Node modifier.  Geometry Nodes will place a Cube at every point along the curve.

How can use the `Delete Geometry` node to remove certain points from the curve before placing the cubes?  What should I pass to the `Selection` input to delete these certain points?  For example if I want to delete points 2,3,6...how can I do it?

Here are my example nodes; currently I have a `Value` passing to the `Selection` which if set to "1" deletes all points, or "0" deletes none:
[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the *Compare* node and all its mathematical modes to pick certain numbers to feed into the *Selection* socket. If you don't want a certain point with a certain index number to not have a cube, you could simply exclude it with a "not equal", for instance:

[image]

You can use other mathematical operations with *Index* as well. Use *Modulo* 3 to exclude every third point from selection:

[image]

...and combine them using boolean logic. *Modulo* 3, but only if they're also indices higher than 8:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, now I see that the `Index` was the input I needed.  Also useful to just use the `Selection` on the `Instance on Points` instead of using the `Delete Geometry` node

Comment: @DavidB Apologies for being to quick on the trigger.

Comment: could you use a noise image to randomly delete the cubes based on how the black and white noise is distributed along the curve index?

Comment: @ben Something [like this](https://i.imgur.com/EApjPcA.png)? _Noise Texture_ values by default are between 0 and 1, which means they're all positive, which means they'll delete all instances if used as is (all positives numbers mean "yes" for boolean purposes). By subtracting 0,5 from it, you can get values between -0,5 and +0,5, which will delete them randomly—you could also use _Math: Round_ node for the same thing. Or a _Map Range_ node for more granular control.

Comment: yes!!! thankyou

Comment: Thankyou! wonderfulz!